# Form with method: "get" makes a POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, http-verbs

This is my form:

```
<%= form_tag(method: "get") do %>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit this form I get a server error because there is no POST action for this URL.  In my routes I have an action for GET, but it's not picked up.  The error goes away when I assign an action to POST at the same URL as the GET.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With your `form_tag` declaration, where should the `get` request go to?

Comment: The current page, so "/" ?

Comment: Try the [How to submit current url](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag#1185-How-to-submit-current-url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comment above says, you'll need to add a path to the form, so it would look something like this...

```
<%= form_tag whatever_the_current_page_is_path, :method => :get %>
```